# Angular js - Application / Controller not working after being moved to a tab

Tags: javascript, angularjs

New to Angular.js.  I consolidated multiple aspx pages, each with a user control onto a single aspx page, moving the user controls to tabs.  Each user control uses angular.js to open and populate a modal window.  The modal popup is no longer working, instead, a postback occurs.

If I move it outside of the `<div class="wb-tabs">` section it works, inside it does not.

### HTML

```
<div class="wb-tabs">
    <div class="tabpanels">
        <details id="Details1" open="open" runat="server">
            <summary>Test Popups</summary>
                <div data-ng-app="positionDataPopupApp">
                    <div data-ng-controller="PositionDataController">
                        <uc2:summary ID="summaryTest" runat="server" />
                            <section id="posnoModal">
                                <%--Modal code removed for brevity--%>
                            </section>
                    </div>
                </div>
        </details>
    </div>
</div>
```

### JavaScript

```
var positionDataPopupApp = angular.module('positionDataPopupApp', [])
.controller('PositionDataController', function ($scope, $http) {    

    $scope.getData = function (positionNumber, orgCode) {
        var paramData = { "OrganizationCode": orgCode, "PositionNumber": positionNumber, "Language": lang };
        var url = positionDataLookupPageUrl + '/GetPositionDetails';

        $http.post(url, paramData)
        .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            $scope.positionDetails = data.d;
            console.log($scope.positionDetails);
        })
        .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            console.log("failed -- ", status); alert(status);
        });

        url = positionDataLookupPageUrl + '/GetCoordinateDegreeDetails';
        $http.post(url, paramData)
      .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
          $scope.coordinateDegrees = data.d;
          console.log($scope.coordinateDegrees);
          var points;
          var totalPoints = 0;
          for (i = 0; i < $scope.coordinateDegrees.length; i++) {
              points = parseInt($scope.coordinateDegrees[i].Coordinate_Degree_Points) || 0;
              totalPoints = totalPoints + points;
          }
          $scope.totalPoints = totalPoints;
          wb.doc.trigger("open.wb-lbx", [[{ src: "#posnoModal", type: "inline" }], true]);
      })
      .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
          console.log("failed -- ", status); alert(status);
      });
    };
});
```

Comment: Please use the angularjs tag when tagging angularjs questions